# Error no p gain specified for pid

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using ros-melodic with gazebo on ubuntu 14.04. I have seen similar errors and tried all of them but still unable to solve mine. Here is the text that is stored in config file.

---

```
robo:
  joint_state_controller:
    type: joint_state_controller/JointStateController
    publish_rate: 50  
  
  joint1_position_controller:
    type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
    joint: joint1
    pid_gain:
      p: 10.0
      i: 0.0
      d: 0.1

  joint2_position_controller:
    type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
    joint: joint2
    pid_gain:
      p: 10.0
      i: 0.0
      d: 0.1

  joint3_position_controller:
    type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
    joint: joint_left_up_cap
    pid_gains: {p: 200, i: 0.01, d: 0.001}
  joint4_position_controller:
    type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
    joint: joint_right_up_cap
    pid_gains: {p: 200, i: 0.01, d: 0.001}
```

---

As you can see I have tried several formats but none worked out.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321232/error-no-p-gain-specified-for-pid/) by [bkti9](https://answers.ros.org/users/40905/bkti9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2019-04-16**:
Can you paste in the error so we can see what problem you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to solve the problem. Its more of format error like said in other posts. In my case it was solved if I write separately (in the same .yaml file):

/robotName/gazebo_ros_controls/pid_gains:
..joint1: {p: 10.0,i: 0.0, d:0.01}

---

Originally posted by [bkti9](https://answers.ros.org/users/40905/bkti9/) with karma: 16 on 2019-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0